# metodo animateCamera recibe valor nulo

Tags: flutter

**buenas noches, tengo un mapa, al cual me gustaría poder ver al momento de realizar una búsqueda me indique el lugar que busque, pero al momento de tocar lo buscado, el método anímate camera me dice que recibe nulo, y no logro conseguir porque, agradecería la ayuda
anexo código e imagen del error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver en su código su error se debe a que en su SearchMapPlaceWidget en onSelected, esta esperando recibir un future de mapController cuando debería de ser su variable _controller, su llamada debería de quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
```